# UIKit dropdown with div inside doesn't disappear. Angular workaround throws $rootScope:inprog error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, uikit

I need to make a workaround to UIKit dropdown, because I want to place clickable `div` element as a menu item, but UIKit reacts (thats mean closes menu) only with click on `a` element.
I'm trying to display notifications as dropdown items with template like: `<a>userName</a> has invited you to <a>event</a>`, but UIKit needs to display dropdown items as `a` elements, so by default I can't nest urls. When I put my template inside `div` menu doesn't disappear after click on text `has invited you`.

This is the piece of UIKit.js code which I want to cheat:

```
if (this.options.mode == "click" || UI.support.touch) {

    this.element.on("click", function(e) {

        var $target = $(e.target);

        if (!$target.parents(".uk-dropdown").length) {

            if ($target.is("a[href='#']") || $target.parent().is("a[href='#']")){
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            $target.blur();
        }

        if (!$this.element.hasClass("uk-open")) {

            $this.show();

        } else {

            if ($target.is("a") || !$this.element.find(".uk-dropdown").find(e.target).length) {
                $this.element.removeClass("uk-open");
                active = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

To work as I expect it needs to get `a` element in line `var $target = $(e.target);`. Then it will pass `if ($target.is("a") || !$this.element.find(".uk-dropdown").find(e.target).length)`, will remove css class `uk-open` and will set flag `active` to `false`.

I made a trick with calling ng-click on li element:

```
 <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-navbar">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" 
         ng-click="itemClicked(item, $event, $index)">
        <div class="menu-item">
            <a href="">Url</a> {{item}} <a href="">Url</a>.
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And inside `itemClicked` function I stop propagation of click event on `div` element and trigger fake click on hidden `a` element:

```
$scope.itemClicked = function(item, event, index){
    event.stopPropagation(); //stops propagation of event 'click' called on "div" element
    angular.element('#target-url' + index).trigger('click'); //triggers 'click' on hidden "a" element;
}
```

It "solves" the problem - menu after item click disappears but I get `$rootScope:inprog` error in console. How can I avoid this? ($timeout doesn't help)

Maybe you have better solution to solve the main problem?

There is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aartek/8y48q/